Response headers are not available
I try to download PDF 2D view from Revit model.
I use this Documentation and this Blog post.
But i cannot get 'Set-Cookie' headers in response body using code from Blog post or code below.
export const getPDFSheet = async (urn: string, derivativeUrn: string) => {
  const response = await autodeskInstanceDownload.get(
    `/modelderivative/v2/designdata/${urn}/manifest/${derivativeUrn}/signedcookies?useCdn=true`,
  );
  console.log('response', response.headers);
};

response.headers in code above doesn't contain any 'set-cookie' headers.
Please advise what i do wrong? The first thing i do is simply copy code from blog, but headers are not available in response.

It could be related to the HTTP client library you used. (i.e. autodeskInstanceDownload.get). In addition, there is not a query string parameter for this endpoint called useCdn.
//index.js

const axios = require('axios');

let urn = ...;
let derivativeUrn = ...;
let encodedDerivativeUrn = encodeURIComponent( derivativeUrn );

let config = {
  method: 'get',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com//modelderivative/v2/designdata/${urn}/manifest/${encodedDerivativeUrn}/signedcookies',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ....', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});


Here is the test result using axios:

